# Exception with java DOM parser

Tags: java, dom

I am using dom pasrer to create xml document where tag name start with digit. 
and it is giving exception. seems with java DOM parser , it is not allowed to have tagname starting with digit.

Same thing ,It is achievable in C#(dot-net) using System.Xml;

is there any way, i can achieve the same.

below is the more progrom and output:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        Element firstname = doc.createElement("1name");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        rootElement.appendChild(firstname);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(CoreDocumentImpl.java:618)
at com.impetus.avatar.WriteXMLFile.main(WriteXMLFile.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java DOM parser is correct to reject these tags.

XML tag names should not *begin* with a digit, but may *contain* a digit.  This is specified in the [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-NameStartChar) document as follows:

```
[4]     NameStartChar ::=   ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | 
                            [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | 
                            [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | 
                            [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | 
                            [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

[4a]    NameChar   ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | 
                            #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

[5]     Name       ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```