# How to create xml root tag which starts with digit in java. Please suggest me any solution

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

How to create xml root tag which starts with digit in java using DOM pareser

```
<6tag>
  <abc>1</abc>
  <cde>2</cde>
</6tag>
```

Comment: As far as I know, XML-Tags cannot start with a digit and probably the Java implementation will try to be standard-compliant. Thus, "using the DOM parser" is probably not possible. Btw, what did you try? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087108/encoding-xml-element-name-beginning-with-a-number .

Answer (score 0):

XML tag names should not begin with a digit, but may contain a digit.

```
[4]     NameStartChar ::=   ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | 
                        [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | 
                        [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | 
                        [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | 
                        [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

[4a]    NameChar   ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | 
                        #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

[5]     Name       ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

Got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627494/3714122)

Answer (score 0):

The [Java XML standards](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12461_01/140/funtional_artifacts_guide/or-fasg-standards.htm) discourage the use of numbers in XML tags, probably because of software compatibility. However, they are legal to use, but not as a first character, as I read [at the W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).